# All distinct permutations of string by cyclic shift of its segment

Tags: string, algorithm

Suppose we have a string A of length n. And we have k <= n.
Now I want to know all distinct strings generated by cyclic shift of any segment of that string of length k, any number of times.

Ex: A = "asdfgh" and k=3.
Then possible permutations are "dasfgh" when segment "asd" is chosen for shifting. Now "dasfgh" can give another permutation "dfasgh" when segment "asf" is chosen.

I want to know if a specific given permutation can be formed or not by such shifts.

Can someone help me by providing some good algorithms or literature or link telling about best approach for solving such questions. I know backtracking can be used but it won't be efficient as n can be as large as 100000.

Comment: This is much to broad for the SO format, and also has nothing to do with C as a programming language.

Comment: Given that this is an ongoing CodeChef problem with little other interest, the literature is very recent and informally published.

Comment: Yes it is from ongoing problem. That is why I want to know about the concept such questions use. It will give me opportunity to learn something new and test if I grasped the concept well or not (I think that is why they keep it 10 days long). I don't want direct ans or the code, I just want to know the correct way of thinking.

Comment: I think it's best to think about it mathematically, using the length of the string A (`n`) and the value of `k`. There are only a limited amount of permutations that can be done with a given length of `n` and `k`. Brute force would require a recursive function on the input string, but think about how that recursive brute force is working and how you can simply set up a mathematical formula to grab the total number of permutations. Next you will need to think about how to handle "distinct." For example, if your input string was `aaaaa`, your result would be 1.

Comment: This is an ongoing programming contest problem.
https://www.codechef.com/OCT15/problems/PERSHFTS